# Is it ok to use spring-orm 3.2.4 with Spring 4.1

Tags: java, spring-mvc, mybatis, ibatis, spring-orm

I am upgrading an old app built using Spring 2.5 to Spring 4.x. The app is using IBatis (now myBatis). Spring orm 4.x has no support for Ibatis any more as it has removed the supporting classes. Spring 3.2.4 still has it. I was wondering if its safe to use a newer version (4.x) of Spring (webmvc, web, context etc) with older version of Spring-orm (3.2.4)
Upgrading Ibatis to Mybatis would increase the scope of the project, for now it is out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not safe.

Spring Framework [introduced a maven BOM](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html#overview-maven-bom) in recent versions to avoid mixing framework versions.